# Optimal Syntax for object creation requiring async calls in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object that has properties that are generated via async functions. I feel like it is calling one, then calling the next, etc. I don't need it to do that but I do need it all be complete before moving on. Below is how I currently do it but I am looking for a more efficient method. I have thought about calling all the functions using Promise.All() in variables. Then creating the object and setting the properties to the variables but I have a feeling someone has a more elegant solution somewhere.

```
let obj = {
prop1 : await functionName(something),
prop2 : await anotherFunction(somethingElse)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.
I was thinking and come up with 2 solutions.

The 1st one is by using `Promise.all` as you mentioned:

```js
function delay(ms = 0) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

async function functionName() {
  await delay(1000)
  return 'value1'
}

async function anotherFunction() {
  await delay(500)
  return 'value2'
}

async function createAsyncObject() {
  const obj = {}

  // Set properties

  await Promise.all([
    functionName().then(v => obj.prop1 = v),
    anotherFunction().then(v => obj.prop2 = v)
  ])

  return obj
}

const obj = await createAsyncObject()
```

The 2nd one I make use of `Proxy` object to make it handle the `Promises`
to set the object's properties:

```js
function delay(ms = 0) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

async function functionName() {
  await delay(1000)
  return 'value1'
}

async function anotherFunction() {
  await delay(500)
  return 'value2'
}

function asyncObjectWrapper(obj) {
  const promises = []
  const then = function then(callback) {
    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => callback())
  }

  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get: (target, property, receiver) => {
      if (property !== 'then') return

      return then
    },
    set: (target, property, value) => {
      if (!(value instanceof Promise)) return true

      promises.push(value)

      value.then(v => target[property] = v)

      return true
    }
  })
}

async function createAsyncObject() {
  const obj = {}
  const wrapper = asyncObjectWrapper(obj)

  // Set properties

  await Object.assign(wrapper, {
    prop1: functionName(),
    prop2: anotherFunction()
  })

  return obj
}

const obj = await createAsyncObject()
```

Comment: I think the first one is super clean and readable. Do you see any performance differences? Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @DaneLooman I don't think there's really any performance difference.
I would say 2nd one with Proxy is more readable and easier to write in my opinion aside from needing an extra function to create the Proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list of name, value pairs by using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and your property retrieval functions.

Once you have this list of entries you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create your new object.

In this example, the property retrieval functions are `getA()`, `getB()` and `getC()`, they could, of course be called anything.

```js
function getA() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'value a'))
}

function getB() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'value b'))
}

function getC() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'value c'))
}

async function getProperty(name, fn) {
    let value = await fn();
    return [name, value];
}

async function getObj() {
    console.log('Getting properties...');
    const entries = await Promise.all([ getProperty('a', getA), getProperty('b', getB), getProperty('c', getC) ]);
    console.log('Properties:', entries);

    const newObj = Object.fromEntries(entries);
    console.log('New obj:', newObj)
}

getObj()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: That is a clever use of Object.fromEntries. Thanks for taking the time to comment.